# Why and how does the final solution provided by the k-means algorithm depend on the initial approximation?

Tags: k-means

Apparently, the final solution provided by the "standard" k-means algorithm depends on the initial approximation of the solution. Why exactly is that? What's the intuition behind it? How does the mathematics behind the algorithm imply this?

I think that an answer should clearly define what an initial and approximate solution is (to avoid ambiguities). Maybe an answer should also describe the exact algorithm to which the same applies.

(I could read a few articles and chapters of books about the topic to figure it out by myself, but, if someone knows the answer and can give me some insight, I don't have to lose much time in searching for it.)

Comment: This video gives a good intuition about the initialization of k-means: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PpH_hv55GNQ

Comment: And in this paper, it's shown why k-means might get stuck in a local optima. https://static.aminer.org/pdf/PDF/000/303/169/on_the_lower_bound_of_local_optimums_in_k_means.pdf